# rake db:seed - ArgumentError: The :dependent option must be one of [:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

So I'm trying to seed my database and I'm getting 
this weird argument error? Any ideas?

Some possibly useful information: I have recently recreated the database and I don't know if this matters but I also recently wiped my hard drive and had to reinstall my local git repo. Please let me know if there are any other files that would be useful in solving this. Thank you!!!

stacktrace:

```
4DV3R54RYs-MBP:Development D35TR0Y3R$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: The :dependent option must be one of [:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify, :restrict_with_error, :restrict_with_exception], but is :destroyend
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:140:in `check_dependent_options
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:90:in `define_callbacks
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:27:in `define_callbacks
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:38:in build
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1259:in has_many
/Users/a666/Development/app/models/post.rb:2:in <class:Post>
/Users/a666/Development/app/models/post.rb:1:in <top (required)>
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in load
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in block in load_file
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in new_constants_in
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in load_file
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in require_or_load
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in load_missing_constant
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in const_missing
/Users/a666/Development/db/seeds.rb:4:in block in <top (required)>
/Users/a666/Development/db/seeds.rb:3:in times
/Users/a666/Development/db/seeds.rb:3:in <top (required)>
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in load
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in block in load
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in load_dependency
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in load
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in load_seed
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in load_seed
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in <top (required)>
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval
/Users/a666/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in <main>
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

seedfile:

```
require 'random_data'

50.times do
  Post.create!(
  title: RandomData.random_sentence,
  body: RandomData.random_paragraph
  )
end
posts = Post.all
100.times do
  Comment.create!(
  post: posts.sample,
  body: RandomData.random_paragraph
  )
end
100.times do
  Question.create!(
    title: RandomData.random_sentence,
    body: RandomData.random_paragraph,
    resolved: false
  )
end
puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{Post.count} posts created"
puts "#{Comment.count} comments created"
puts "#{Question.count} questions created"
```

Comment: As the message says, you must have a typo in Post model. It looks like missing newline before `end`

Comment: Awesome. I found it. Thank you!